# Searching inside the Payload of redis

Tags: python, redis, redisearch

I want to search inside the payload of a value in Redis using Flask.

This is the code that I have written

```
# to fetch value:
localhost/suggestions?prefix=<name>
@app.route('/get')
def get():
    try:
        prefix = request.args.get('prefix')
        n = prefix.strip()
        result= ac.get_suggestions(n, fuzzy = True,with_payloads=True) 
        return(json.dumps([{'id': item.string, 'score': item.score,'payload':item.payload} for item in result]))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I tried to search for a value present in the payload, but an empty list was returned.

I went through the following things:

- https://github.com/RediSearch/redisearch-py/blob/master/redisearch/auto_complete.py
- https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/2.0/payloads/
- https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/1.4/python_client.html

EDIT:

imports:

```
import redis
import redisearch
import json
import string
from flask import Flask
import logging
#flask to expose api's to outside world
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify,render_template
from flask_restx import Resource
from redis import Redis, ConnectionPool
from redisearch.auto_complete import AutoCompleter,Suggestion
from _util import to_string
ac = AutoCompleter('ac')
app = Flask("autocomplete")
```

New value add:

```
# localhost/add?name=<name>
def add():
    try:
        name = request.args.get('name')
        n = name.strip()
        payload = {
                "data": {
                    "value": "1",
                }
            }
        ac.add_suggestions(Suggestion(n,1.0,json.dumps(payload )))

        return "Added Successfully"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return "Addition Failed"
```

I have even tried searching on the web but was unable to find a suitable solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question would be better with the Flask aspect taken out, as it's irrelevant, and an example of how to *insert your sample data to redis*, so that people can re-create the problem where the empty list appears.  That would make the question a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please back the `import` statements so we know what `ac` is. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell done with that

Answer (score 0):

The only fault I can see in your code is that you reference the variable `n` in two places, when perhaps you mean `prefix` and `name`.  For example in the function `add`:

```
ac.add_suggestions(Suggestion(n,1.0,json.dumps(payload )))
```

Looks like it should actually use `name` as submitted by the user:

```
ac.add_suggestions(Suggestion(name ,1.0,json.dumps(payload )))
```

Then in your `get` function, use `prefix`:

```
result = ac.get_suggestions(prefix, fuzzy = True,with_payloads=True)
```

I'm confused as to why this doesn't throw an exception (unless you have `n` declared as a global var somewhere else in your code).

---

I tried some code in my environment with: `RediSearch version 2.0.12`...

```
>>> from redisearch.auto_complete import AutoCompleter,Suggestion
>>> ac = AutoCompleter('ac')
>>> payload = {
...         "data": {
...             "value": "1",
...         }
...     }

>>> words = ['aoo','boo','soo','rep','mep']
>>> for word in words:
...     ac.add_suggestions(Suggestion(word, 1.0, json.dumps(payload )))
... 

>>> res = ac.get_suggestions('oo', fuzzy = True,with_payloads=True) 
>>> res
[soo, boo, aoo]
```

Now for your list comprehension:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([{'id': item.string, 'score': item.score,'payload':item.payload} for item in res])
[{'id': 'soo', 'payload': '{"data": {"value": "1"}}', 'score': 1.0},
 {'id': 'boo', 'payload': '{"data": {"value": "1"}}', 'score': 1.0},
 {'id': 'aoo', 'payload': '{"data": {"value": "1"}}', 'score': 1.0},]
```

This appears to return the payload for every hit.

Comment: I was getting the payload , the issue with n I think is that when I copied that code , that particular line got skipped. 
What i actually want is that to be able to search inside the payload data

Comment: Ex: if I enter the prefix as 'data' then I want all the items which have 'data' inside the payload to be reflected.